# Sort fault with values over 1000

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have a problem sorting rows From lowest value to highest value

Current list of sorted items (column D):

```
DBB1172 
DBB1178 
DBB1184 
DBB1196 
DBB1202 
DBB1208 
DBB332 
DBB338 
DBB344 
DBB350 
DBB356
```

What it should be:

```
DBB332
DBB338
DBB344
DBB350
DBB356
DBB1172
DBB1178
DBB1184
DBB1196
DBB1202
DBB1208
```

My code:

```
LastUsedRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Valve").Range("C4").End(xlDown).row
lastusedcolomb = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Valve").Range("C4").End(xlToRight).Column
NumberOfItems = LastUsedRow - 3
Debug.Print NumberOfItems
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Valve").Range("C4:S" & LastUsedRow).Sort key1:=Sheets("Valve").Range("D:D"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
orderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

Comment: you are sorting strings, not numbers

Comment: You can pad the numeric portion with leading zero's before sorting; or split into two columns and sort numeric and alpha portions separately.

Answer (score 2):

If a helper column is fine then supposing your data is in column A.

In the helper column, put formula, say cell B2:

```
=MID(A2,4,99)+0
```

Copy down and then while sorting, sort on column B (Ascending).

Comment: The only way to sort this without a helper column is to write a new sort algorithm. None of the built in Excel sort algorithms can do such a sort.